# Работа с Form1 из подключаемой DLL

Tags: delphi

Всем Доброго времени суток. Вопрос прост. В моей программе есть `Label`, а ещё у меня есть `DLL` в котором написана функция/процедура которая хотела бы написать что-нибудь в `Label` родителя, как это можно реализовать? Проблема в том, что ещё до этапа компиляции, всё что относится к `Label` или `Form` подчёркивается красным и соответственно не компилируется. Каким путём можно передать данные от `DLL` в программу? Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы не сделать в DLL функцию (допустим function MyFunc: PChar) возвращающую некий текст, а затем писать:
    Label.Caption := MyFunc;

Comment: Пока разбираюсь с примером который был написан в виде ответа, но почему-то был стёрт. Ваш вариант, praddos, и правда всё бы решил, но хочется подоставать их библиотеке различные объекты расположенные на главной форме. Вот ответ metalurgus интересен, но про его реализацию я так и не услышал, а хотелось бы именно такой вариант опробовать.

Comment: может это подойдет
procedure TForm1.MyProc(AOwner: TComponent);stdcall;
var
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;
begin
PropInfo := GetPropInfo(AOwner.ClassInfo, 'Caption');
if PropInfo <> nil then
  SetStrProp(AOwner,'Caption','MyCap')
else
  begin
    PropInfo := GetPropInfo(AOwner.ClassInfo, 'Text');
    if PropInfo <> nil then
      SetStrProp(AOwner,'Text','MyTxt')
    else
      ShowMessage('No string property');
  end;
end

Comment: Большое спасибо praddos, заработало. Очень красивый пример.

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо когда программа, которой нужно управлять своя (имеется исходный код). В этом случае вариант praddos лучший. Но когда нужно управлять или ввести что нибудь в поля чужой программы (.exe) то на этот случай:

```
  var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ParentWnd: HWND;
  ChildWnd:HWND;

  ParentWnd := FindWindow(nil, PAnsiChar(hOldCaption));
  ChildWnd:=FindWindowEx(ParentWnd, 0,'Button','');
  ChildWnd:=FindWindowEx(ParentWnd, 0,'Edit',nil);
  if(ChildWnd <> 0)  SendMessage(ChildWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Только нужно точно знать имена элементов управления чужого приложения и их иерархию. Для этого рекомендую http://s0m.narod.ru/iws_inst.zip

Comment: Спасибо, вариант интересен и в будущем я бы о нём спросил.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы научиться передавать параметры в функции, прежде чем пробовать писать DLL.  
В DLL библиотеке в функции одним из параметров передайте тот лейбл, в котором нужно что-то поменять.  
И вызывая эту функцию в своей программе передайте туда нужный лейбл.

Comment: лучше передавать не лейбл, а коллбэк и лейбл менять в головной программе в этом коллбэке.

Comment: Скажите, а как передать данные объекты на примере Label? Скажем, при примитивном случае